# Runtime error when making multiple form requests (posts) to .aspx web site using Python and the Requests module

Tags: python, forms, python-requests

I am using Python and its Requests module. I have a requests.session() up and I log into a .aspx site. All is fine at this point. The following code is then run in a while loop until a certain time of day or until 5 errors occur:

```
response = session.post('https:/.../default.aspx', data=formdata)
```

Every time the script loops through this post request, I parse the response to get two values in a list. My results over 1 day are shown below:

Format: TIME [Number, Number]

```
LOGIN TIME:  07:11:32
07:11:33 [a, b]
Error:  0
Error:  1
Error:  2
Error:  3
07:45:51 [c, d]
07:45:58 [e, f]
07:46:02 [g, h]
07:46:05 [i, j]
08:02:34 [k, l]
09:25:26 [m, n]
11:15:59 [o, p]
11:38:46 [q, r]
11:42:34 [s, t]
Error:  4
```

The letters are placeholders for the numbers returned from the parsed xml response. My script shuts down after 5 errors or until the time of day is 1:00 pm. The time of the errors and loop count is shown below:

TIME, RESPONSE STATUS CODE, LOOP COUNT (# iteration through while loop)

```
07:12:45, 500, 452
07:12:45, 500, 453
07:12:46, 500, 454
07:12:50, 500, 455
11:51:46, 500, 106818
```

After the first error and each error beyond that the script sleeps for an increasing amount of time (sleep(errorcount**2) where error count is 1 to 4 - the 5th error as previously mentioned shuts the script down), which explains the difference in time of the first four errors.
Anyway, the response status code of 500 is accompanied with the following response.content (cut down for brevity):

```
An exception occurred while processing your request. Additionally, another exception occurred while executing the custom error page for the first exception. The request has been terminated.
```

Which seems like a generic server error to me. Anyway, any suggestions would be great. I have a gut feeling that I am posting at a too higher frequency but that doesn't make sense if (as shown in my results) it works from 7:45 to 11:51 am. I believe the posts begin working after the 4th error as the loop sleeps (sleep(4**2) = 8) 8 seconds after the fourth error, possibly giving the server time to get its act together?

not sure though, anyway, thanks in advance for any help/advice.

Comment: 500 errors are out of the control fo either you or python-requests. This could be a form of rate-limiting if you are in fact making requests to the site too frequently.

Comment: I had a feeling it might be a rate limiting measure, however I have tried this on other days which have had the same or even more loop counts without any errors at all :-/, very confusing ...